# Remove the 'X' (clear button) from the input type date and change the font family in Firefox

Tags: html, css, date, firefox, input

I have an input type field in my form, but in Firefox I am not able to remove the X icon (clear button) that appears when I have a date value set inside the input.

Moreover, I cannot change the font family in that input. It seems to be the Courier font family instead of the Arial font family, which is currently set as default in the whole website.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the font-problem ? Writing " font-family : Arial " in the " .datetime-reset-button " in elements inspector doesn't work ?

Comment: Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60624857/7424232

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to remove the clear button in FireFox. The ::ms-clear feature is only for Microsoft browsers, as described in the MDN documentation.

Answer (score 0):

### X or clear button

Even though the class referring to the clear button can be found through Shadow DOM inspection (i.e. **.datetime-reset-button** from *datetimebox.css*):
[image: Clear button class]
[image: shadow path]

And direct changes in the inspector/devtools work (e.g. add `display: none` to the class), [shadow root access and shadow elements manipulation/attachment is not allowed in `<input>` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow), leading to a "*DOMException: Operation is not supported*" if `myInput.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})` is attempted (e.g. [*:host-context* MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host-context%28%29#examples)).

An alternative/workaround is to place an overlay image/background on the input's container through `::after`:

```CSS
@-moz-document url-prefix() { /* apply rules only to Firefox */
  .my-datetime-input-container::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    right: 0.25rem;
    background: url(/images/overlay.svg) white no-repeat;
     /* or simply use background: white; */
    background-size: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
  }
}
```

This overlay prevents clicks/taps on the Shadow DOM clear button because it's literally covering it (needs an opaque background to completely hide it).

### Font family issues

Changing the input's font, may be a specificity issue, attempting a more specific selector may be enough to apply the rule:

```CSS
.my-datetime-input-container input[type="date"].my-specific-class {
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

Where:

```HTML
<div class="my-datetime-input-container">
  <input type="date" class="my-specific-class" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you could try this :

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
```

But the documentation warn about the `::-ms-clear` CSS pseudo-element.

> Non-standard This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Check this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3A-ms-clear

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. Anyway, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Maybe I wrote the wrong input type, as you mentioned a date value, try also with **[type=date]**

Comment: `-ms` is a Microsoft prefix, and the support table shows as much.