# Any solution to remove clear button <input type="time"/> on Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, input

I tried to disable-hide the clear button and didn't work for `Firefox`.

But on `Chrome`, `Edge`, `Safari` it works fine. Any idea why? Is there a solution?

Following is the `CSS`:

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-clear-button {
  display: none;
}
```

See the [Image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiqdw.png)

Comment: already answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655250/is-it-possible-to-disable-input-time-clear-button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to disable input=time clear button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655250/is-it-possible-to-disable-input-time-clear-button)

Comment: yeah, i already found that question before, but i didn't get any answer why in firefox doesn't work, or how can i make it

Answer (score 4):

`<input type="time" required>` hides the reset button.

Source: I reviewed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1479708. :)

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-clear-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work on Firefox :( still there the clear icon

Comment: You could also try this yourself before posting it and see that it doesn't resolve the problem at all.